# FruxePi Installation fails on RPI W

Tags: python, rpi.gpio, pip

I've been trying to install FruxePi (https://github.com/fruxefarms/FruxePi), both 0.3 & 0.4 versions. But [image: Running installation with -log essentially gives me this error]

To my understanding the setuptools / pi fails to install, but I can't imagine a way to solve this.

I've been trying to google anything I can for several weeks, with no luck... Any suggestions?

Comment: What command are you running and what is the error message?

Comment: Please post a text log of what you're doing. Don't post screen shots - they aren't useful. Ensure you're run the install with `python3 -m pip ...` (not python2).

Answer (score 0):

The installation instructions is described on [the given link](https://github.com/fruxefarms/FruxePi):

```
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/fruxefarms/FruxePi.git
cd FruxePi
sudo bash install.sh
```